# Android font is not applied for button via style

Tags: android, fonts, android-styles, android-typeface

I created style for `Button`

```
<style name="MainButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_main_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/btn_main_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@font/bold</item>
</style>
```

This style applies in the `AppTheme`

```
 <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MainButtonStyle</item>
```

`bold.ttf` file is in `res/font` folder

If I run an app I still see the default font. Where is the catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textAppearance` allows you to define text-specific styling: font family, font color, size, etc. It is not for referencing font resource.

Just use the `fontFamily` attribute to set the font in xml:

```
<style name="MainButtonStyle">
    ...
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/bold</item>
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="MainButtonTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/btn_main_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/bold</item>
</style>

<style name="MainButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_main_selector</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@Style/MainButtonTextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

make your button style inherit from parent Button style like

```
<style name="MainButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<style name="MainButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_main_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/btn_main_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/bold</item>
</style>
```